# When does the slope of $x^x$ equal zero?

Tags: calculus

My work so far is

$$f'(x) = x^x(\ln(x) + 1)$$

I was just told it does not exist, though.

Comment: $x=1/e$ makes the bracket vanish.

Comment: And other zeros do not exist.

Comment: Am I allowed to work in the real projective line ?

Comment: @Renato, why not? It seems I forgot that $\ln$ could have negative outputs such as -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x^x = e^{x\log{x}}$. So long as you are only considering this on the positive real axis, the only point at which this could be zero is zero, since elsewhere $x\log{x}$ is finite and $e^y$ is never zero. However, $x\log{x} \to 0$ as $x \downarrow 0$, so $x^x$ is also nonzero at zero.

Hence the only root can be when
$$ \log{x} = -1, $$
or $x=1/e$.

Comment: Ah that's better :) +1!